# Sharepoint Failover Server Not Working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

I have configured sharepoint failover database server as instructed here http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=202 and on Microsoft Technet Site too here http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2010/12/29/sharepoint-2010-is-now-mirroring-aware.aspx.

But after bringing down the Primary database server all I get on the Sharepoint Web Application is an unexpected error has occurred.

Can anyone please show me where to look to find out why sharepoint is not failing over the mirror instance of the database mirror.

Note: I am running Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the log files are at

C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS\

The log file location can be configured in Central Administration -> Operations -> Diagnostic Logging.

You will have to check the logs on all servers in your farm.

Comment: I already know where the log file for sharepoint is located and it is here C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS\, I can see a line there where SHarepoint attempts to connect to the primary database and times out and it seem not to connect to the failover at all

Answer (score 0):

This what i have found from MS:

Please check out link

FIX: Cannot connect to a named instance after failover on a mirror server in SQL Server 2014 or 2016

Applies to: SQL Server 2016 DeveloperSQL Server 2016 EnterpriseSQL Server 2016 Enterprise CoreSQL Server 2014 DeveloperSQL Server 2014 EnterpriseSQL Server 2014 Enterprise CoreSQL Server 2014 Standard

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159748/fix-cannot-connect-to-a-named-instance-after-failover-on-a-mirror-serv